# Почему у меня не удаляется сессия?

Tags: php, сессия

Есть код

```
<? if ($_SESSION['steamid'] = "YES") {
             echo '<a href="logout.php"><input type="image" src="img/logout.png"></a>';
         }else { include ('steam_auth.php'); }?>
```

Оно всегда выдаёт картинку из `img/logout.png` а в **logoutp.php** написано:

```
  <?
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['steamid']);
session_destroy();
header ("Location: index.php");
exit;
?>
```

Почему у меня сессия не unset'ается?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472123/why-session-destroy-not-working

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-unset.php

Comment: если 2 разных файл то в каждом нужно прописывать
session_start(); и не пойму зачем в условии присваиваешь YES может сравнить ==

Answer (score 1):

Все верно ты присваиваешь YES потом чистишь сессию потом снова  присваиваешь YES

Answer (score 1):

У вас в первой строчке вместо оператора сравнения используется оператор присвоения:

```
<? if ($_SESSION['steamid'] = "YES") {
```

То есть вы каждый раз присваиваете переменной `$_SESSION['steamid']` значение `YES`, которое проверяется на истинность и поскольку строка `YES` приводится к булеву типу и равно истине, то вы всегда ходите по кругу.

Нужно исправить проверку аутентификации путем добавления еще двух знаков равенства:

```
<? if ($_SESSION['steamid'] === "YES") {
```

Это частая ошибка, причем даже опытных разработчиков. Просто на внимательность проверка. В некоторых стандартах кодирования есть даже правило смены мест операндов. Вот если так написать ваше условие и допустить опечатку, то будет системная ошибка, которая сразу укажет место и сэкономит уйму времени:

```
<? if ("YES" === $_SESSION['steamid']) {
```